# Function from C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I need to transform these encryption system developed in C# to PHP. These are the input data. Customer ID, JSON object transformed to string and a private key.

codigoCliente: **1002**

datos: **{"codigoCliente":1002,"codigoArticulo":"30-07483","cantidad":1}**

claveSecretaServicio: **RFlTfDIwMjBXZWJQYWdlX0V4dGVybmF**

I need to get this HASH as result: **WGHGEY830J3WeadO1o4NGNLYZ9lY7xvquol5igE+hLU=**

This is the call in C#:
GetHash(modelo.CodigoCliente.ToString(), JsonSerializer.Serialize(modelo), “WGHGEY830J3WeadO1o4NGNLYZ9lY7xvquol5igE+hLU=”);

The C# functions to transform to PHP are these.

```
public static string GetHash(string codigoCliente, string datos, string claveSecretaServicio)
{
    var claveSecretaBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(claveSecretaServicio);
    var claveOperacion = Encrypt3DES(codigoCliente, claveSecretaBytes);
    var firmaBytes = GetHMACSHA256(datos, claveOperacion);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(firmaBytes);
}

private static byte[] Encrypt3DES(string codigoCliente, byte[] key)
{
    var codigoClienteBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codigoCliente);
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] SALT = new byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    tdes.BlockSize = 64;
    tdes.KeySize = 192;
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    tdes.IV = SALT;
    tdes.Key = key;
    var cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(codigoClienteBytes, 0, codigoClienteBytes.Length);
    tdes.Clear();
    return resultArray;
}

private static byte[] GetHMACSHA256(string data, byte[] key)
{
    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
    {
        byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        return hashValue;
    }
}
```

I don't know C# so I don't really understand the detailed workings of the functions to change them to PHP.

I have tried this but my HASH result is different.

```
/********************
 *      3DES
 ********************/
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key)
{
    $method = 'des-ede3-cbc';
    if (strlen($message) % 8) {
        $message = str_pad($message, strlen($message) + 8 - strlen($message) % 8, "\0");
    }
    $iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($message, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv); //Force zero padding.
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}

/********************
 *      SHA 256
 ********************/
function mac256($ent, $key)
{
    $res = hash_hmac('sha256', $ent, $key, true); // TRUE (PHP 5 >= 5.1.2)
    return $res;
}

/********************
 *      BASE 64
 ********************/
function encodeBase64($data)
{
    $data = base64_encode($data);
    return $data;
}
function decodeBase64($data)
{
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    return $data;
}

/********************
 *      HASH
 ********************/
function createHash($codigoCliente, $data, $key)
{
    $key = decodeBase64($key);

    $keyOperacion = encrypt_3DES($codigoCliente, $key);

    $res = mac256($data, $keyOperacion);

    return encodeBase64($res);
}
```

I've gotten a valid 3DES PHP function (thanks to Michael Fehr)

```
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key)
{
    $method = 'des-ede3-cbc';
    if (strlen($message) % 8) {
        $message = str_pad($message, strlen($message) + 8 - strlen($message) % 8, "\0");
    }
    $iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($message, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv); //Force zero padding.
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

but I still need the other two to achieve the valid HASH. Perhaps if I you read this Michael Fehr.

Your function is correct and I get the same intermediate 3DES value that is achieved with C#: **PD8fSM4gz3s=**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The codes provide the same result on my machine. If it's different on your machine, please post a complete example, i.e. sample data and the calls to the methods involved.

Comment: Added functions call data and result string to get.

Comment: Your addition is not really helpful. Simply posting the test data is not enough, what is interesting is how you pass the data to `GetHMACSHA256` and `mac256` and of course the output, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The `GetHash` and `createHash` methods, which were not included in the original question, are not actually needed (problems with this would be the subject of a second question).

Comment: I have rewritten the problem to see if it is clearer now and I think you already have all the necessary data now. Thank you

Comment: This data still does not work with the C# code. In the key data the padding is missing. But even if this is added, the Base64 decoded key has a length of 23 bytes and is therefore not a valid 3DES key. For a repro, better post the call to the `GetHash` method with the parameters that should provide the expected hash value.

Comment: This is the call: GetHash(modelo.CodigoCliente.ToString(), JsonSerializer.Serialize(modelo), “WGHGEY830J3WeadO1o4NGNLYZ9lY7xvquol5igE+hLU=”);

Comment: I was able to determine the required key from the posted key, reproduce the expected hash with the C# code and finally adjust the PHP code, please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The posted Base64 encoded key `RFlTfDIwMjBXZWJQYWdlX0V4dGVybmF` results Base64 decoded in `DYS|2020WebPage_Externa` and thus has a length of 23 bytes. This is too short for TripleDES, which requires a 24 bytes key. A plausible key that additionally has the required length of 24 bytes is `DYS|2020WebPage_External`, which is Base64 encoded `RFlTfDIwMjBXZWJQYWdlX0V4dGVybmFs`. This is probably a copy/paste issue.

Since the passed data corresponds to a JSON string, a corresponding class, in the following called `Modelo`, has to be defined, initialized according to the posted sample data and passed as JSON string.

Then the following C# code returns the expected hash:

```
class Modelo
{
    public int CodigoCliente { get; set; }
    public string CodigoArticulo { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
...
Modelo modelo = new Modelo
{
    CodigoCliente = 1002,
    CodigoArticulo = "30-07483",
    Cantidad = 1
};
string hash = GetHash(modelo.CodigoCliente.ToString(), JsonSerializer.Serialize(modelo), "RFlTfDIwMjBXZWJQYWdlX0V4dGVybmFs");
Console.WriteLine(hash); // WGHGEY830J3WeadO1o4NGNLYZ9lY7xvquol5igE+hLU=
```

---

In the PHP code, in the `encrypt_3DES` method, the result must *not* be returned Base64 encoded, but as raw binary data. In addition, a class corresponding to the `Modelo` class of the C# code must be implemented, initialized according to the posted sample data, and passed as JSON string.

The following PHP code returns the expected hash value corresponding to that of the C# code:

```
<?php
/********************
 *      3DES
 ********************/
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key)
{
    $method = 'des-ede3-cbc';
    if (strlen($message) % 8) {
        $message = str_pad($message, strlen($message) + 8 - strlen($message) % 8, "\0");
    }
    $iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($message, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv); //Force zero padding.
    return $encrypted; // base64_encode($encrypted); // Fix: Return the raw data and not the Base64 encoded data
}

/********************
 *      SHA 256
 ********************/
function mac256($ent, $key)
{
    $res = hash_hmac('sha256', $ent, $key, true); // TRUE (PHP 5 >= 5.1.2)
    return $res;
}

/********************
 *      BASE 64
 ********************/
function encodeBase64($data)
{
    $data = base64_encode($data);
    return $data;
}
function decodeBase64($data)
{
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    return $data;
}

/********************
 *      HASH
 ********************/
function createHash($codigoCliente, $data, $key)
{
    $key = decodeBase64($key);

    $keyOperacion = encrypt_3DES($codigoCliente, $key);

    $res = mac256($data, $keyOperacion);

    return encodeBase64($res);
} 

// Define a Modelo class as in the C# code
class Modelo 
{
    var $CodigoCliente;
    var $CodigoArticulo;
    var $Cantidad;
    function __construct( $CodigoCliente, $CodigoArticulo, $Cantidad)
    {
        $this->CodigoCliente = $CodigoCliente;
        $this->CodigoArticulo = $CodigoArticulo;
        $this->Cantidad = $Cantidad;
    }
}

$modelo = new Modelo(1002, '30-07483', 1);
$hash = createHash($modelo->CodigoCliente, json_encode($modelo), "RFlTfDIwMjBXZWJQYWdlX0V4dGVybmFs");
print($hash); // WGHGEY830J3WeadO1o4NGNLYZ9lY7xvquol5igE+hLU=
?>
```

---

A further note: Apparently the data (`datos`) are to be hashed with a HMAC and the key used for this (`claveOperacion`) is derived from a client ID (`CodigoCliente`) in combination with a password (`claveSecretaServicio`). To derive the key for the HMAC, an encryption with TripleDES is applied. More contemporary seems to me a derivation with a reliable key derivation function, such as PBKDF2.

Comment: Many thanks. The solution works perfectly. I have done several tests and the HASH obtained is correct. Thank you really Topaco for your help and your involvement.